# jQuery .attr() multiple attributes

Tags: jquery, attributes

Attempted to retrieve attirbutes of an element using the .attr function. I dynamically create an input element using and assign the value to the class attribute.

```
$('.item-selection-amount').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

This will return:

```
item-selection-amount ui-corner-all price
item-selection-amount ui-corner-all 66.00
```

**price** is always different, but is it possible to pull the third value of the class attribute such as `attr('class[2]')` etc?

Comment: i dont think it would be good idea to store price in class attr. since the term 'class' defines a group of elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `class` attribute **incorrectly**.
It is intended to be used for visual presentation.

What you want to do is to **attach data** to an element.

For that purpose you can **use HTML5 `data-` attributes**:

```
$('.item-selection-amount').data('price', 66.00);
// ... later
$('.item-selection-amount').click(function(){
  console.log( $(this).data('price') );
});
```

If you want to add price to the element just render the HTML similar to one below on the server:

```
<li class='item-selection-item' data-price='66.00'>Something</li>
```

Comment: didnt know u could do this! this is great.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have prices included in HTML as CSS classes?
You can't really rely on the order of CSS class names, unless you set them up in HTML and never change in JavaScript.
You should generally manipulate and test CSS classes in jQuery using
[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/),
[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/),
[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and
[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

For storing data consider using data- attributes:

```
<span class="item-selection-amount" data-price="66.00">...</span>
```

and it would be easy to use with jQuery:

```
$('.item-selection-amount').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('price'));
});
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xz2Ra/). Instead of span you can use whatever tag you are using right now.

Answer (score 1):

If the class always has three classes, you could split them by space and get the 3rd index.

```
$(this).attr('class').split(" ")[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are positive its always going to be the 3rd element in the class, you can do this:

```
$('.item-selection-amount').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[2]);
});
```

This breaks the class up by spaces, and pulls out the 3rd element.

However if you are trying to store information about a product in the "class" field. A better option would be to use a data attribute, which is supported under HTML5 (and doesn't break anything in older non-HTML5 browsers). For example:

```
<li class="item-selection-amount" data-price="66.00">My Product</li>
```

Comment: `this.className`, please - using the awesome power of jQuery to get an attribute off a single element isn't exactly efficient

Answer (score 0):

Start perhaps with

```
var arrClasses = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
```

Then you can either loop over that until you get one that matches a regex, OR, if you're confident that it'll always be in position 3 (and I wouldn't be confident) you can try as you say, and just go with

```
arrClasses[2]
```

to get the price from your example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
$('.item-selection-amount').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[2]);
});
```

this is only answer what you need,
but don't put any data on class tag,